# Log in failed CLIENT_UNAUTHORIZED [769] on Web terminal of AWS LightAail

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I'm using AWS LightAail on Ubuntu.

Initially Web based Terminal was working fine, but when I did

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I got an error

```
Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.
CLIENT_UNAUTHORIZED [769]
```

Answer (score 1):

0 ) SSH into your instance using a terminal app like in example below, but only provide a real filename of your ssh key and your real ip

```
$ ssh -i ".ssh/LightsailDefaultKey-.pem" ubuntu@000.000.000.000
```

1 ) add following 2 lines to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/lightsail_instance_ca.pub
CASignatureAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

2 ) Restart

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```